# Extention method not working for List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add an extension method to make it simpler to add items to a List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))

I'd like to be able to define the list like so...

```
Dim myList = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) From {
    {"key 1", "value 1"},
    {"key 2", "value 2"}
}
```

My extension method looks like this...

```
<Extension()>
Public Sub Add(list As IList(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)), key As String, value As String)
    list.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(key, value))
End Sub
```

For some reason it doesn't work. The compiler just continues to complain that it can't convert a String to a KeyValuePair(Of String, String).

Comment: I think this might be a C#-exclusive feature.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/MeXHYB

Comment: Your extension must be defined in a Module.  The module namespace must be imported wherever you call the extension method.

Comment: Which version of VS/VB are you using?

Comment: VS 2017. I've been able to get other extension methods to work, but for some reason it doesn't like the KeyValuePair extension. I've just used the regular initialisation for now. I'll revisit it when I have a bit more time.